# Change Adsense account linked to DoubleClick for Publishers

Tags: google-adsense, google-dfp

We use DoubleClick for Publishers (DFP) Small Business.

Can I change the AdSense account that was used when we created the Doubleclick account?   I'd like to link a different AdSense account.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that your AdSense account is permanently linked to your DFP account.

If you have a new AdSense account, you need to create a new DFP account as well.  You will then have to set up all your advertisers in the new DFP account and change the JavaScript tags on your website.

See this discussion on the Google product help forums: [Created new AdSense account, but old one linked to my DFP account](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/dfp/0HGadmQwClE).   Other people have had the same issue and there are some tips on migrating advertisements from one DFP account to another.

Comment: Can I link another adsense account? [link](https://support.google.com/dfp_sb/answer/188529?hl=en) . But I can not find "Link an AdSense account" in Global settings?